# Safari & blocking iframe content from different domain

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, amazon-s3, safari, cors

I am having an issue with Safari blocking content from a sourced Iframe.  Here is the scenario...

Test URL: http://sprungstage.com/iframetest/

I am framing a book on Amazon S3 that is located here:
http://sprungtest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/california_eus_eb/index.html

It works in all browsers except Safari.

On Amazon, I added this CORS config to the bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

On the sprungstage.com server, I added this in my .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

However, in Safari the content wont appear and the console shows a bunch of blocked frame errors like this:

```
[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "http://sprungtest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://sprungstage.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
    (anonymous function) (swfaddress.js, line 8)
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It seems this is limited to the Flash app (SWF).  I tried a sample just using an image and is worked fine: http://sprungstage.com/iframetest-noflash/ .

I also put crossdomain.xml on both servers to no avail.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?